# using header() to rewrite filename in URL for dynamic pdf

Tags: php, pdf, mod-rewrite, rename, http-headers

I have a php script that generates a pdf report. When we go to save the pdf document, the filename that Acrobat suggests is report_pdf, since the php script is named report_pdf.php. I would like to dynamically name the pdf file, so I don't have to type the appropriate name for the report each time that I save it.

Asking on a news group, someone suggested this, where `filename="July Report.pdf"` is the intended name of the report

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: filename="July Report.pdf"');
```

But it doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong, or will this work at all? Is this a job for mod_rewrite?

---

So I've tried both

```
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="July Report.pdf"');
```

and

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="July Report.pdf"');
```

( not at the same time ) and neither work for me. Is this a problem with my web host? For this [url](http://nerdcraft.net/pdf/report.php), here's my code:

```
<?
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="July Report.pdf"');

// requires the R&OS pdf class
require_once('class.ezpdf.php');
require_once('class.pdf.php');

// make a new pdf object
$pdf = new Cpdf();
// select the font
$pdf->selectFont('./fonts/Helvetica');
$pdf->addText(30,400,30,'Hello World');
$pdf->stream();

?>
```

Comment: If you want the file to be downloaded (and not openend in the browser) , add these:

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');

Otherwise, you should still include the line
header('Content-Type: application/pdf')
so you browser knows how to open the file.

Comment: Also, you might be missing the content-length for the file - some browsers open files correctly without this and some don't. To get this, dump all the output into an output buffer, then print out the headers and specify one as 'Content-Length:'**the strlen of the output buffer***

Comment: Temporarily comment those php header lines and see the output. It should NOT contain any php errors. Apply back the headers after you fix any errors if so.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="July Report.pdf"');
```

or

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="July Report.pdf"');
```

Another option would be to use the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to pass your "July Report.pdf" - an example link might be:

```
<a href="report_pdf.php/July%20Report.pdf?month=07">
```

That file should default to saving as "July Report.pdf" - and should behave exactly like your old php script did, just change the code that produces the link to the pdf.

Comment: That href trick worked! Now, what about %20 in the filename when I go to save it? ;)

Answer (score 10):

Should be:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename="July Report.pdf"');
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://github.com/rospdf/pdf-php/raw/master/readme.pdf (Page 19)
The stream-method accepts an array as parameter:

> `stream([array options])`
>   Used for output, this will set the required headers and output the pdf code.
>   The options array can be used to set a number of things about the output:
>
> > `'Content-Disposition'=>'filename'` sets the filename, ...

This code works well for me

```
$ezOutput = $pdf->ezStream(array("Content-Disposition"=>"YourFileName.pdf"));
```

In my case I use `ezStream()` but I think `stream()` should give the same result.

Comment: Actually the accepted doesn't work for me. This one actually works!! Hence thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the name shown on the title tab in the browser

I had the same problem, then i found that it's metadata missing inside my .pdf.
I used a tools ("debenu PDF tools") for edit pdf property like author, title, etc...
I just change title from empty field to what title I want, upload the new pdf and now, with same code, same script the browser show the right name!

For the name when u ask to save document

is what u specify in header filename=

Comment: Setting the PDF title in the metadata also fixes the filename shown in the top left corner when viewing the PDF in Chrome. For those using FPDF to dynamically generate PDFs, use `$pdf->SetTitle('Your Title');`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove spaces from file name using hyphens? So, I think its name must be like this; filename=July-Report.pdf