# Rename file before downloading PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm currently making a file hosting website. I'm having a problem with renaming the file before the user downloads the file. When the file is uploaded the original name is saved in the mysql database and the file is renamed to a id.

```
<?php

  require("includes/inc.php");

$id = trim(sanitize($_GET['id'])); //Receives the id of the file from the url

if($id) {
    $fileid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = '$id'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($fileid) != 1) {
        header('Location: download.php?error=invalid_file');
        exit();
    } else {
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array($fileid)) {
        $fileid2 = $info['id'];
        $filename = $info['name'];
        $ext = $info['ext'];
        $filesize = $info['size'];
        $downloads = $info['downloads'];
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header("Location: uploads/".$fileid2.".".$ext);
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
        }
?>
```

Comment: I hope `$fileid2`, `$filename`, and `$filesize` are sanitized before being stored into the database, to prevent HTTP header injections.

Comment: What is the problem? I don't see any code to send the file to the client, but otherwise nothing stands out...

Comment: You're using `$fileid2` in the `header`. If I understand you correctly, you want this to be a different name, correct?

Comment: Yes, I would like the name to be changed to $filename

Comment: Isn't `$info['name']` the original file name?

Comment: I think he wants the original filename.

Comment: Chris check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015985/using-header-to-rewrite-filename-in-url-for-dynamic-pdf

Comment: @RobertPeters - Not sure. Chris, please clarify

Comment: Ok, when a file is uploaded it is renamed to a random id for example 14.zip and saved in a folder then the original filename is saved in a mysql database. What I want to do is download the file 14.zip from the upload folder but before that 14.zip is renamed to the original filename stored in the mysql database.

Comment: If in fact `$filename = $info['name'];` contains the original file name, your code should work as-is

Comment: When it downloads the file the filename is still the random id. It doesn't rename it to original name.

Comment: `var_dump($info['name'])` and make sure the value is the original name

Answer (score 0):

I would think your "while" loop and output would be something like this: (I also switched the $filename and $fileid2 in the headers)

```
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($fileid)) {
            $fileid2 = $info['id'];
            $filename = $info['name'];
            $ext = $info['ext'];
            $filesize = $info['size'];
            $downloads = $info['downloads'];
    }

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileid2.'.'.$ext.'"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);

readfile(uploads/".$filename.".".$ext);
```

I did not test this, so I hope it helps.