# How to change the filename displayed in the "Save as..." dialog from .php to .png

Tags: php, png, gd

A simple PHP script that I picked up from stackoverflow generates a PNG with a transparent background, writes some text on it then directly outputs it to the client browser:

```
$font = 25;
$string = 'My Text';
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
imagealphablending($im, false);
$white = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);
$lime = imagecolorallocate($im, 204, 255, 51);
imagettftext($im, $font, 0, 0, 30, $red, "fonts/tt0588m_.ttf", $string);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

The scope is to obtain a simple service that feeds an image based on the parameters passed to it via URL, such as Google Charts (e.g. [this QR code image](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&chl=lsajdfgksdafgs&choe=UTF-8&chld=L%7C0)).

So far, so good, except that if I click on the image generated with the code above and want to save it, the browser doesn't recognize it as being a PNG image, but a *PHP script* (*Save as type* selector has this option only), as oposed to the Google Charts example, where the resource is clearly identified as a PNG file.

How do I achieve this correct resource identification by the browser?

Comment: Have you tried a `Content-Disposition` header to change the suggested filename?

Comment: Is the font you are trying to access with `imagettftext` available on the server where you are running this?

Comment: @Frits van Campen I haven't tried anything, I didn't know what to :)

Comment: Yes, the font exists and the output is there. It's just that if I click "Save as...", the image is not recognized as PNG by the browser (apparently).

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any output before this image? Check your network log in the browser for response headers

Comment: There isn't any other output before that, no.

Comment: And the browser is receiving `Content-type: image/png` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what the header value is: `Content-Type:image/png`.

Comment: This is the live example, by the way: [http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/text.php](http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/text.php). The scope is to create a script that feeds images generated based on the URL parameters passed to it, so that that image resource can be accessed within the `src` attribute of an `<img />` tag.

Comment: Sorry about the dead-end link above, here's a correct live example: [http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/text.php?text=This%20is%20a%20dummy%20text](http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/text.php?text=This%20is%20a%20dummy%20text). The idea is to provide the text to generate via URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using header() to rewrite filename in URL for dynamic pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015985/using-header-to-rewrite-filename-in-url-for-dynamic-pdf)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Browser will use the filename from the URL as the default value in the "Save as..." dialog. You can *type* another name of course or save the file using the suggested name (text.php) and rename it afterwards.

You can use the [Content-disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) header to "suggest" a filename to the browser. Here is an example:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=mytext.png");
```

- `inline` suggests that browser should attempt to display the image. Change it to `attachment` to suggest that the browser should display the "Save as..." or similar dialog.
- `filename=` should contain the filename of your choice.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I did check the file-name assignment when doing drag-and-drop of the image outside of the browser (not save-as). I presumed the behaviuor would have been the same with save as but as you checked it is not. So ignore my comment...