# How can I "hint" to browsers a filename for saving a dynamic image to disk?

Tags: php, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to change the filename displayed in the “Save as…” dialog from .php to .png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181948/how-to-change-the-filename-displayed-in-the-save-as-dialog-from-php-to-pn)

My PHP-generated GUI displays a dynamically-generated PNG image:

```
<img src="someScript.php?dataId=xyz&width=250&height=200" alt="Chart" />
```

The image contents are dynamic and unique based on the `dataId` argument:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
// output image based on $_GET['dataId']
?>
```

But when my users try to right-click and Save As in IE, Firefox or Chrome, the suggested filename is `someScript.php.png`. This is non-unique and not very useful.

**How can I "hint" to browsers as to what the "save as" filename should be?**

Browsers can always do what they like, but the precedent set by HTTP's `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<filename>` implies to me that there may be some way of hinting at a filename. This HTTP header itself is not appropriate because the I want the `Content-Disposition` to remain at [the default of `inline`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.2).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `filename` argument [is also supported](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.3) for [`Content-Disposition: inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment):

> `[RFC6266]`: **4.3. Disposition Parameter: 'Filename'**
>
> The parameters "filename" and "filename*", to be matched case-insensitively, provide information on how to construct a filename for storing the message payload.
>
> Depending on the disposition type, **this information might be used** right away (in the "save as..." interaction caused for the "attachment" disposition type), or **later on (for instance, when the user decides to save the contents of the current page being displayed).**

So:

```
<?php
$filename = "image_" . $_GET['dataId'] . ".png";

header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"{$filename}\"");

// output image based on $_GET['dataId']
?>
```

Comment: True, but don't expect all browsers to process this. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#inlwithasciifilename