# Display a pdf with PHP not displayed correctly

Tags: php, pdf

I have some pdf files on a storage server and i want to show them to the users without showing them the real file path, and i want to do this with PHP.

I tryed this:

```
$file = 'https://storage.server_test.com/agc/catalogs/catalog1.pdf';
$filename = 'catalog.pdf'; 

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
```

But the pdf is not displayed at all and i get this error: `This PDF document might not be displayed correctly.`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try the same with a local file?

Comment: No, because the files are not stored localy. They are stored on a storage server, so i have only the absolute path to them.

Comment: Did you check that `filesize` and `readfile` work as expected with non-local files?

Comment: As i said, my example is not working, that's why i posted the question. You want to suggest that it should work ?

Comment: No. I would suggest you try to `var_dump(filesize($file), readfile($file))` (without the silence operator!)

Comment: This is not working. I get the same gray page with the error: This PDF document might not be displayed correctly

Comment: Try viewing the source (if you browser can do that) or simply remove the pdf content-type while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried embedding it using html `object` tag?

```
<object data="https://storage.server_test.com/agc/catalogs/catalog1.pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="https://storage.server_test.com/agc/catalogs/catalog1.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Alternatively in php, try this header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

Finally, if `@readfile($file)` isn't working, try:

```
echo @file_get_contents($file);
```

---

After trying this myself locally, I think I managed to get it working. Try this:

```
<?php

$remote_pdf = 'http://www.saronicferries.gr/content/pdfFiles/sample.pdf';
$remote_file_name = end(explode('/', $remote_pdf));
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'. $remote_file_name .'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($remote_pdf);

?>
```

Output:

[image]

I think what was the problem is that `filesize($file)` was failing for remote file. After removing that and `header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');`, it works.

Comment: As i said, i want to do it from php because i dont want the user to see the real path to the file.

Comment: Answer updated. Try that header or alt way of reading remote content.

Comment: I've tryed the last line and i get something like this: %PDF-1.6 %âãÏÓ 3948 0 obj <>stream hÞTÊ± Ã Ð_q‹RˆwWShR×@ .... printed on the screen

Comment: It works now. Thanks ! Do you think this question is usefull for others too?

Comment: One more thing, in the tab it says: untitled - pdf. Can i rename that ?

Comment: This is definitely one of those FAQ. When trying to output binary contents like image/pdf etc... if the php code has error, it will just make it look like the image/pdf is broken. I believe that's why others way saying check if `readfile` and `filesize` were working (i.e. test the function without the headers to see the error).

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora - I think `basename()` function might not be retrieving the file name correctly, thus not setting it on the header. I've updated my code again, try that. If that doesn't work, that's a separate question for SO.

Comment: Seems like the name remains untitled - pdf even after this changes.

Comment: Looks like this is already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015985/using-header-to-rewrite-filename-in-url-for-dynamic-pdf - I believe you can only set the filename if the `Content-Disposition` is `attachment` - i.e. send the file to browser for download...