# title_for_layout while viewing pdf with cakeResponse

Tags: cakephp, pdf, title

i'm viewing pdf files from database using this function:

```
public function pdfPreview($taskId){
    $file = $this->StoredFile->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'StoredFile.id' => $taskId
        ),
        'contain' => false
    )); 

    $this->response->body($file['StoredFile']['data']);
    $this->response->type('pdf');
    //$this->response->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline');

    //Return response object to prevent controller from trying to render a view
    return $this->response;
}
```

Is there any way to set title for layout with CakeResponse while not rendering layout, because i'm trying to set filename as title, but i didn't found solution?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, change what is being displayed in the browsers titlebar?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `$title_for_layout` view var is passed to the html and put between `<title>` tags.

However, as I understand, you are outputting a PDF using raw data from de database. This is then interpreted by the browser to render a PDF view. The browser thinks it is displaying a file, so when you set the filename in the `Content-Disposition` header it will display this in its title. Like they do on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016016/1535656