# How to get the type of data from a URL

Tags: c#

After implementing the basic version of simple downloader, I have spent a few hours googling to know how to get the type of my URL say *.mp3,*.mp4 etc.for sites such as daily motion etc who's URL don't have it appended at the end.This is because my Downloader works for these types but a link without specific types makes it  to download a Kb's file having nothing to play.

Here is the code to determine the content-type to decide the *.extension for downloading:

```
     WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
         string datastring = myWebClient.DownloadString("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1viyeu_pakistani-actress-meera-reema-saima-dance-on-faisal-ahmed-music-album-launch_news");
        NameValueCollection headers = myWebClient.ResponseHeaders;
        foreach (string key in headers.AllKeys)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Header:{0},Value:{1}", key, headers[key]);


        }
```

It returned me a list of outputs on Console among which a line was:

Header:Content-Type,Value:text/html;charset=utf-8

Now i want to hear that how will this help me to counter the issue already described.

Suggestions please

Here is the code for downloader

```
    private void downloadbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

        //Declarations for string objects
        string downloadURL, path;
        //raw URL taken from user
       downloadURL =  this.downloadURL.Text;
        path = this.savePath.Text;


       Uri tmp = new Uri(downloadURL);
       string EndPathFileName = tmp.Segments.Last();
       path = path + @"\" + EndPathFileName;

       //downloads file using async method

       myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(tmp, path);

       downloadbtn.Text = "Download Started";
       downloadbtn.Enabled = false;

       myWebClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
       myWebClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);




    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as i heard the same MIME etc.but couldn't figure out.?

Comment: Figuring duplicates is a fairly easy job :-)

Comment: This was asked before but now the text/html has more to do

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a `Content-Type` header that can give you a hint of what file type to expect.

Many times the server will also provide information regarding the filename - see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015985/using-header-to-rewrite-filename-in-url-for-dynamic-pdf) on how it is usually done on the (PHP) server side.

Comment: If you are referring to something like this:    NameValueCollection headers = myWebClient.ResponseHeaders;
           foreach (string key in headers.AllKeys)
           {

               Console.WriteLine("Header:{0},Value:{1}",key,headers[key]);

           
           }

Comment: But it's returning NullReference Exception

Comment: which one of the lines casts the exception?

Comment: NameValueCollection headers = myWebClient.ResponseHeaders

Comment: Seems like the viewer's are no more interested

Comment: I don't know what that means... Are you sure you are executing this code after you execute the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

according to this
 http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1

```
Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body.
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that a site doesn't return response ..i experiemented for one such site

Answer (score 0):

you can get a content-type and split it like:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com") as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            string contentType = "";

            if (response != null)
                contentType = response.ContentType;
            int start = contentType.IndexOf('/');
            int end = contentType.IndexOf(';', start); 
            string yourext = contentType.Substring(start+1, (end - start)-1);//like mp3,png,txt
        }
```

Comment: Does WebClient supports a method like this as i am using that throughout my project

Comment: Your code doesn't determine it for https://archive.org/download/27/items/AllahHuAllahHu/AllahHuAllahHuimranShaikh.wmv

Comment: this url return this error!
The item you have requested has a problem with one or more of the metadata files that describe it, which prevents us from displaying this page.

Comment: What about the original issue;though i came to know how to get the contents out of responseheaders but what is its linkage now to  resolve the issue for which i posted !!!

Comment: well, a line such as: Header:Content-Type,Value:text/html;charset=utf-8   will help me how to use for the purpose @Yehia

Comment: My code already working good,see this image
http://im70.gulfup.com/cEmIJ4.png
What is error?

Comment: it doesn't work for links like https://archive.org/download/27/items/AllahHuAllahHu/AllahHuAllahHuimranShaikh.wmv

Comment: Also simple links work but others like http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x27hsb9_dunya-news-nation-celebrates-3rd-day-of-eid_news fails

Comment: But for simple link(s) (where it works) how should it help me to solve my problem for which i posted .Moreover info like, Header:Content-Type,Value:text/html;charset=utf-8  ...how value should be used

Comment: I have found a rather more sophisticated code at:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx  but how will it help me @Yehia